# iOS - CAShapeLayer anti-aliasing?

Tags: ios, calayer, antialiasing

I have two rhombus shapes next to each other, and I'd like the edges of them to fit together seamlessly.

At the moment, due to anti-aliasing, the background bleeds through even though the edges are as close together as possible.  I'd like not to have to overlap the shapes.

Does anyone have any tips?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like this.

```
yourLayer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest;
```

You'll need to import QC first but you prob already have.

**EDIT**

magnificationFilter
The filter used when increasing the size of the content.

@property(copy) NSString *magnificationFilter
Discussion
The possible values for magnificationFilter are shown in “Scaling Filters”. The default value is kCAFilterLinear.

Availability
**Available in iOS 2.0 and later.**
Declared In
CALayer.h

Comment: Thanks for your response. This didn't seem to do anything. This was the code I used ([tile base] returns the CAShapeLayer):

[self.layer setMagnificationFilter:kCAFilterNearest];
[self.layer addSublayer:[tile base]];

Comment: You'll need to set the magnificationFilter on the actual CAShapeLayer. Also, I haven't used this with nested layers so you may have to set it on ALL layers that contain the shape layer.

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything either. Would there be another property that might override this? Or something else I should turn on?

Comment: Filter properties including magnificationFilter are undefined on iOS. This will have no effect.

Comment: No, that's not correct, I use magnificationFilter in my Game of Life app on iOS. It definitely works.