# Path-based mask with nice anti-aliasing

Tags: ios, calayer

I'd like to mask a square with a circle. I'm using this instead of corner radius because of something I'd like to do with animation later.

I can get it to mask, but the edges are very rough:

[image]

```
  // Target View
  let targetView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
  targetView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

  // Mask
  let maskingPath = UIBezierPath()
  let half = targetView.frame.width / 2
  maskingPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: half, y: half), radius: half, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)
  let maskingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  maskingLayer.path = maskingPath.CGPath

  // Maybe setting contentsScale?
  // maskingLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale // doesn't change anything, sorry 
  // Maybe enabling edgeAntialiasing?
  // maskingLayer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true // also doesn't change anything
  // Magnification filter?
  // maskingLayer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest // nuttin'

  targetView.layer.mask = maskingLayer
```

I've tried [magnificationFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683934/ios-cashapelayer-anti-aliasing) and a few other things.

How do I add an animatable circle mask that's antialiased?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I just tried this and it works fine. It's possible some code you're not showing here is affecting things.

Comment: I don't know what could make it complete except maybe defining the targetView. I just added that to the code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving `addArcWithCenter` an angle in degrees:

```
maskingPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: half, y: half),
                             radius: half,
                             startAngle: 0,
                             endAngle: 360,
                             clockwise: true)
```

but [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:) states that the angle should be in radians.

Because of this, you're creating a path that overlaps itself, several times. The edge is drawn on top of previous passes of the edge, in the same place. After enough passes build up, they end up looking opaque (or nearly so).  You would see something similar if you created multiple circle paths on top of each other.

This works better for me:

```
maskingPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: half, y: half),
                             radius: half,
                             startAngle: 0,
                             endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0),
                             clockwise: true)
```

(But since you really want a closed oval, you should use `UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: targetView.bounds)`, as you did in your answer.)

Comment: Oh, this is definitely it, yeah. "multiple partially transparent passes will look opaque". I love finding the root cause, thanks Kurt!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, but not a root cause.

This will draw crispy:

```
let maskingPath = UIBezierPath()
let half = targetView.frame.width / 2
maskingPath.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: half, y: half), radius: half, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360, clockwise: true)
let maskingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskingLayer.path = maskingPath.CGPath
targetView.layer.mask = maskingLayer
```

This will draw nice and antialiased:

```
let maskingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskingLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: targetView.bounds).CGPath
targetView.layer.mask = maskingLayer
```

Wish I knew why. They're both `CGPath`s used as a layer mask.

EDIT: Kurt points out that I'm drawing `360` radians, which is like drawing the same circle over and over again, appearing opaque and ruining any antialiasing that was happening.